# Finding dimensions of a rectangular box to optimize volume

Tags: calculus

A rectangular box (base is not square) with an open top must have a length of $3ft$, and a surface area of $16 ft^2$. Compute the dimensions of the box that will maximize its volume.

I am going wrong somewhere but I can't see where. I have set $2(3h+3w+hw)=16$ and my optimization equation is $v=hwl$. I set $w=\frac{8-3h}{3+h}$ and plug into the optimization equation. Calculating $v$' gives me $\frac{9h^2-84h+72}{{(3+h)}^2}$, but setting that equal to zero does not give me the answer I need for h, which is $1$.

Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget that the top of the box is open? The surface area is

$$2(3h+hw) + 3w=16,$$

so that

$$w = \frac{16-6h}{3+2h}.$$

The volume of the box is

$$V = 3hw = 3h\frac{16-6h}{3+2h}.$$

If you differentiate this with respect to $h$, and set it equal to $0$, you get the $h$ for which the volume is maximized.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is going wrong you forgot to subtract the top so itll be $2(3b+bh+3h)-3b=16$ here b=breadth and h=height . Now you proceed by the way as you did and you will get an equation in h for volume diffrentiate it and put it to be $0$ . Thus we get eqn $\frac{48h-18h^2}{3+2h}$ so on differentiating wrt h we get a quadratic as $h^2+2h-4=0$ thus $h=\frac{-1+,-\sqrt{4+16}}{2}$ so we take positive sign for max area thus its $-1+\sqrt{5}$ now you can get breadth and you are done with the sum. Hope it helps you.